# Laravel Resource Controller missing Method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a laravel resource controller as follow:

BlogController.php

```
class AdminBlogController extends BaseController {

public function index()
{
  // some code
}
public function create()
{
 // some code
}
```

// etc.....

in route.php I have this :

```
  Route::resource('blog', 'AdminBlogController');
```

now I understand that when you go to URL /blog , it goes to index() and when you go to /blog/create goes to create() method.

My question is how do I handle missing method? for example when some types /blog/test , I get an error there , how can I redirect back missing methods to /blog?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#handling-missing-methods):

> If you are using resource controllers, you should define a __call
>   magic method on the controller to handle any missing methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your AdminBlogController, add a `__call` magic method:

```
public function __call($method,$parameters = array())
{
    if (!is_numeric($parameters[0])) {
        return Redirect::to('blog');
    }
    else {
        $this->myShow($parameters[0]);
    }
}
```

...and, importantly, you need to rename your `show` method to something else (`myShow` in this example). Otherwise, `/blog/test` will route to `show` with the expectation that `test` is an id of a blog that you want to show. You also need to specify, in your `__call` method, which parameters after `blog/` should be considered IDs, and which should be considered missing methods. In this example, I allow any numeric parameter to be treated as an ID, while non-numeric parameters will redirect to Index.